# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7601: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-unicode, urldecode

I am currently running: Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64).

ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7601: ordinal not in range(128)

When running the below code I get the above error. When I save and try to open the txt file from a local directy I experience the same error, however, when I save and run a duplicate, that I shorten to ~25 lines the run as expected -- any guidance would be very much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import seaborn
import urllib.request


urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt','stations.txt')

print(open('stations.txt','r').readlines()[:10])
```

Comment: Did you check what encoding was used for the file? I'm sure the NOAA specifies that somewhere. Then use that encoding when opening the file.

Comment: Also, if you only need the first 10 lines, don't read the whole file first; it's a large file. `from itertools import islice`, then `lines = list(islice(openfileobj, 10))` would give you the first 10 lines of an open file object without reading the rest.

Comment: Was only print the first 10 lines to see if it was working properly, as it is is a large file.

Comment: I'm curious why if I delete the majority of the document the code will run (i.e. if i delete all of the txt file down to 50 lines then print the first 10 it will work, but not when the file is full) -- is it possible for certain lines to be encoded differently than others in a txt?

Comment: Everything works in ipython, however, does not work the same when I try to run in sublime text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: @jmh1092: different locale; you are not specifying an encoding, so `locale.getpreferredencoding()` is used to determine what codec to use. Never rely on the default.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the [documentation for that directory](http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/readme.txt) does not specify what codec is used for the files, so I opened the file in binary mode instead and found the bytes that caused 'offense'.

The data is encoded as UTF-8; the 'offending' bytes you encounter spell out ESPAñOLA:

```
>>> line
b'US1NMRA0022  36.0456 -106.1517 1955.0 NM ESPA\xc3\xb1OLA 5.4 WNW                           \n'
>>> line.decode('utf8')
'US1NMRA0022  36.0456 -106.1517 1955.0 NM ESPAñOLA 5.4 WNW                           \n'
```

That's the 63815th line in the file, if you are curious, which is why you don't see this issue when you truncate the file.

Open the file with that codec:

```
open('stations.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
```

Don't rely on the default, which depends on your locale (which easily differs from environment to environment).

Comment: That worked perfectly, needed to add the encoding layer!